# Let $G$ be an abelian group with identity $e$. Let $H=\left\{g\in G\mid g^2=e\right\}$. Show that $H\le G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group with identity $e$. Let $ H = \left \{ g \in G \mid  g^2 =e \right \}$. Show that this is a subgroup of $G$.

My answer:

We have four principles to be valid in order for $H$ be a subgroup of $G$:

(i) is closed

Obvious point, easy to prove

(ii) is associative

This is more trickier and I might need your help here. I thought of the following solution for $ h \in G $ 
$ g*(g*h)=(g*g)*h$  / multiply both sides by $g$
$g^2 *gh=g^2 *hg $ so $ e*gh=e*hg $ since it's abelian $gh=hg$ Is it a right way of thinking about it?

(iii) Identity, I thought of $e$ but it doesn't work $ g*e \neq g$ So what might it be?

(iv) Inverse of $g$ would be $g$

I formulate questions related mainly to point (iii).

Thank you

Comment: The product in $H$ is the product in $G$, which we already assume to be associative.  And of course $g*e=g$, why would you think otherwise?

Comment: True. Thank you. So how about part iii

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why did you say $g*e\ne g$?

Comment: I edited my comment to cover $iii$.  I don't understand why you doubt that $g*e=g$.

Comment: Because I don't understand why g*e =g despite the fact that e is the identity of G

Comment: Why "despite the fact"?  That's the definition of the identity element.

Comment: So does it mean that every group which have some identity e will have the same identity for every particular subgroup? I don't know if H is a subgroup and I want to check it. Maybe I overestimated the exercise. Thank you for responses

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You only have to check two properties, given $H$ is not empty (it contains $e$):

(i) If $h, h'\in H$, then $hh'\in H$, i.e. 
$$\forall h\:\forall h'\enspace(h^2=e)\wedge(h'^2=e)\implies (hh')^2=e,$$
which results from $G$ being abelian.

(ii) If $h\in H$, then $h^{-1}\in H$, i.e.
$$\forall h\enspace h^2=e\implies (h^{-1})^2=e,$$  which results from $hh^{-1}=e$, so 
$$e=e^2=(hh^{-1})^2=h^2(h^{-1})^2=e(h^{-1})^2=(h^{-1})^2.$$

Comment: Don't we also have to check that $H$ is nonempty?

Comment: It obviously contains at least $e$.

Comment: Well, yes, since $e^2=e$; but it's a requirement nonetheless.

Comment: Sure, but conciseness is also a quality in maths. Anyway, I only wrote a sketch.

Comment: Then indicate that in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove $H\le G$ is the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Since $e=ee=e^2$, we have $e\in H$, so $H$ is nonempty.

Let $g, h\in H$. We show that $gh^{-1}\in H$. Indeed,

$$\begin{align}
(gh^{-1})^2&=gh^{-1}gh^{-1}\\
&=g^2(h^{-1})^2\\
&=e,
\end{align}$$ since $G$ is abelian.

Hence $H\le G$.